# Can't create named pipe for remote: "The handle is invalid."

Tags: c++, winapi, window, named-pipes

I am trying to create named pipe server for remote using `127.0.0.1` but after I run `CreateNamedPipe` it failed with error 6 which means:

> The handle is invalid

I also tried to add `PIPE_ACCEPT_REMOTE_CLIENTS` but it doesn't work.

This is my server code:

```
LPCWSTR pwsPipePrefix = L"\\\\127.0.0.1\\pipe\\";
LPCWSTR pwsPipeName = NULL;
HANDLE hServerPipe;
BOOL bSuccess;
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
DWORD messageLenght;
BOOL bAttemptImpersonation = TRUE;

// Read name pipe name to from STDIN
wchar_t wcInputPipeName[200];
wprintf(L"[*] Pipe name to connect to (max 200 chars): ");
std::wcin.getline(wcInputPipeName, 200);
int iInputLen = wcslen(wcInputPipeName);
if (iInputLen > 200) {
    wprintf(L"[-] More than 200 chars (%d).. exiting.\n", iInputLen);
    return 1;
}
std::wstring wsConcat = pwsPipePrefix + (std::wstring)wcInputPipeName;
pwsPipeName = wsConcat.c_str();
wprintf(L"[*] Creating named pipe: %ls\n", pwsPipeName);
hServerPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    pwsPipeName,            // name of our pipe, must be in the form of \\.\pipe\<NAME>
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE, // open mode, specifying a duplex pipe so server and client can send and receive data
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_ACCEPT_REMOTE_CLIENTS, // MESSAGE mode to send/receive messages in discrete units (instead of a byte stream)
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,                   // number of instanced for this pipe, 1 is enough for our use case
    2048,               // output buffer size
    2048,               // input buffer size
    0,                  // default timeout value, equal to 50 milliseconds
    NULL                // use default security attributes
);

wprintf(L"[*] Waiting for incoming connections...");
bSuccess = ConnectNamedPipe(hServerPipe, NULL);
if (bSuccess) {
    wprintf(L"Got one.\n");
}
else wprintf(L"Error: %d", GetLastError());
```

*This piece of code was taken from [this project](https://github.com/csandker/InterProcessCommunication-Samples/blob/master/NamedPipes/CPP-NamedPipe-Basic-Client-Server/CPP-Basic-PipeServer/CPP-Basic-PipeServer.cpp).

Comment: *"after I run `CreateNamedPipe` it failed with error 6"* - you don't know that, and that isn't what the posted code checks. You're blindly assuming `CreateNamedPipe` succeeded. The error you'r reporting is the result of the failure to `ConnectNamedPipe`, not `CreateNamedPipe`. Check the handle returned from `CreateNamedPipe`. If it returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` then *that* is the point to reap `GetLastError()` for debugging that failure (and you can forget about invoking `ConnectNamedPipe` thereafter, as it is pointless to do so).

Comment: `L"\\\\127.0.0.1\\pipe\\"` is invalid prefix for `CreateNamedPipe`. you can use it only in call `CreateFile`. really `CreateNamedPipe` failed

Comment: Thanks, it make sense.